# How to save in C the tcpdump results in a file?

Tags: c, string, variables, system, tcpdump

I'm writing a C program to do a tcpdump on my device. I'm executing the command in C as a normal terminal command with system(" figure out why this doesn't do what I think you want"); anyway, I want to save the results in a file I want to save the results in a file whose name is indicated by a variable in C. How can I do it? Here is my code: (the variable is **file_name**, which is the variable that contains the name of the file where I want to save the results)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

    char string_year[20];
    char string_month[20];
    char string_day[20];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    //printf("now: %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
    int year = tm.tm_year + 1900;
    int month = tm.tm_mon + 1;
    int day = tm.tm_mday;
    //printf("%d\n", year);
    sprintf(string_year, "%d", year);
    //printf("%s\n", string_year);
    //printf("%d\n", month);
    sprintf(string_month, "%d", month);
    //printf("%s\n", string_month);
    //printf("%d\n", day);
    sprintf(string_day, "%d", day);
    //printf("%s\n", string_day);
    char file_name[80];
    strcat(file_name, string_day);
    strcat(file_name, "_");
    strcat(file_name, string_month);
    strcat(file_name, "_");
    strcat(file_name, string_year);
    strcat(file_name, ".pcap");
    printf("%s\n", file_name);


    system("tcpdump -i eth0 -w file_name");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `char cmd[128]; snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "tcpdump -i eth0 -w %s", file_name); system(cmd);`

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're better off just writing a Bash script or a one-liner.
`tcpdump -i eth0 -w "$(date "+%m_%d_%Y.pcap")"`

Comment: A shell scripts seems a good choise, more than a C program ... If you want manage programmatically the output of tcpdump you may use the C function `popen`, this function allow you to get a line per line input of the execution of a program! Again, to analyze programmatically you may write a filter I.E. `tcpfilter` with C and then you may  execute from the command line something like ` tcpdump -i eth0 | tcpfilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char system_input[100];
sprintf(system_input, "tcpdump -i eth0 -w %s", file_name);
system(system_input);
```

Comment: Your code is a right solution, but if I insert this 3 lines into my code, and try to substitute "tcpdump -i eth0 -w" with "touch" (only to see if file_name is correct), this is my file name in the folder. '�'$'\003''3_8_2021.pcap' .... do you know why?

Comment: `char file_name[80];
    strcat(file_name` - `file_name` is not initialized, so you can't `strcat` to it. Either initialize it with zero terminator or `strcpy`. But overall, just `snprintf` it instead of `strcat` anyway. And do not use `sprintf` - use `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

the first item placed in `file_name[]` must be done via `strcpy()`  -or- via `file_name[0] = '\0'`

Then all other data can be appended via `strcat()`